# Time saving coding - assistance request

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataset with 180 columns with a different field title such as Tec, Tea, Tck.........

I need to take each of these columns and split the values and add an average and increase column to the data for each of the parameters (the column titles).  So far im using the code below but there is surely an easier way of automating this?

```
#Tec

dftecraw1 = dfplayerstatraw2[['UID','Tec']]
dftecraw1[['Tec min','Tec max']]=dftecraw1['Tec'].str.split('-', expand = True).apply(pd.to_numeric).fillna(0)
dftecraw1 ['Tec Average'] = dftecraw1[['Tec min','Tec max']].mean(axis=1)
dftecraw1 ['Tec Inc'] = dftecraw1['Tec max'] - dftecraw1['Tec min']
dftec= dftecraw1.drop('Tec', axis=1)

#Tea

dftearaw1 = dfplayerstatraw2[['UID','Tea']]
dftearaw1[['Tea min','Tea max']]=dftearaw1['Tea'].str.split('-', expand = True).apply(pd.to_numeric).fillna(0)
dftearaw1 ['Tea Average'] = dftearaw1[['Tea min','Tea max']].mean(axis=1)
dftearaw1 ['Tea Inc'] = dftearaw1['Tea max'] - dftearaw1['Tea min']
dftea= dftearaw1.drop('Tea', axis=1)

#Tck

dftckraw1 = dfplayerstatraw2[['UID','Tck']]
dftckraw1[['Tck min','Tck max']]=dftckraw1['Tck'].str.split('-', expand = True).apply(pd.to_numeric).fillna(0)
dftckraw1 ['Tck Average'] = dftckraw1[['Tck min','Tck max']].mean(axis=1)
dftckraw1 ['Tck Inc'] = dftckraw1['Tck max'] - dftckraw1['Tck min']
dftck= dftckraw1.drop('Tck', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of the values that change, and then iterate over that list.

```
fields = ['Tec', 'Tea', 'Tck', ...]
for field in fields:
    dftecraw1 = dfplayerstatraw2[['UID', field]]
    dftecraw1[[f'{field} min', f'{field} max']]=dftecraw1[field].str.split('-', expand = True).apply(pd.to_numeric).fillna(0)
    # etc etc
```

Comment: This is working but only for the last field in the fields = list (ie. Tck int he above example)

Comment: @THough Probably because of the last line of code in each block `dftec= dftecraw1.drop(field, axis=1)`

Comment: @THough That creates a separate variable name, which won't work with my solution.

Comment: @THough You would probably need to create a new dictionary to store those variables, and assign it like this `newdictionary[field] = dftecraw1.drop(field, axis=1)`